# Fetch data from reports

Tags: email, charts, pardot

I have a requirement where I want to show charts , graphs or pull data from reports in pardot email template. Is their any way I can do that either in pardot or from salesforce itself ?

Comment: Can you let us know, what have you tried yet.

Comment: Right now I am just exploring, I have no approach to try.